# TCL: printing csv file report by tcllib report

Tags: csv, tcl

I'm trying to create nice looking report of csv file which contain:

```
,column_1, column_2,column_3,column_4
line_1,1,2,3,4
line_2,5,6,7,8
line_3,9,0,1,2
line_4,3,4,5,6
```

The following is my TCL code:

```
#!/bin/sh
# \
exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}

lappend auto_path .../tcllib/

package require csv
package require struct::matrix
package require report


struct::matrix data
set f [open my.csv "r"]
csv::read2matrix $f data , auto

report::defstyle simpletable {} {
data set [split "[string repeat "| " [columns]]|"]
top set [split "[string repeat "+ - " [columns]]+"]
bottom set [top get]
top enable
bottom enable
}

report::report r 5 style simpletable
r printmatrix data
```

When I execute it I get:

```
**report/matrix mismatch in number of columns**
```

What I did wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I test with *exactly* what you provided (except that I have a system copy of tcllib; the exact versions I tested with were Tcl 8.5.2, csv 0.7.3, struct::matrix 2.0.2, report 0.3.1, all from ActiveTcl) then it worked fine and produced this output:

```
+------+--------+---------+--------+--------+
|      |column_1| column_2|column_3|column_4|
|line_1|1       |2        |3       |4       |
|line_2|5       |6        |7       |8       |
|line_3|9       |0        |1       |2       |
|line_4|3       |4        |5       |6       |
+------+--------+---------+--------+--------+
```

All I can think of is that your *real* data must be not exactly what you think it is. Is there an extra comma on the end of one line of your data?

Comment: Hello Donal, for your answer. Fortunately the data file is OK but I found that I was need to modify last line of my code: "r printmatrix data" --> "puts [r printmatrix data]".

Comment: Ah yes, didn't think to mention that. Most Tcl commands don't print output direct because that reduces their flexibility. :–)